# Option footer-html returning error when used within KnpSnappyBundle

Tags: symfony, footer, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to build invoice pdf with wkhtmltopdf library and a symfony2 wrapper [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy).

I want to add a footer on every page with the wkhtmltopdf option footer-html. In command-line, everything works fine, my pdf is built and a footer is repeated on every page. But when I use the bundle service :

```
$snappy = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
$snappy->setOption('footer-html', 'http://www.google.com');
$content = $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html);

return new Response(
    $content,
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
    )
);
```

it returns an error :

```
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
Error: Failed loading page http://www.google.com (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError
"
stdout: ""
command: C:\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --lowquality --dpi "300" --margin-bottom "0" --margin-left "0" --margin-right "0" --margin-top "0" --page-size "A4" --background --encoding "utf-8" --footer-html "http://www.google.com" "http://www.google.com" "test.pdf".
```

Did any already succeed in using footer-html option with KnpSnappyBundle ?

Comment: try `setOption('footer-html', 'google.com');` and report back please - wkhtmltopdf falls back to `http://` protocol by default.

Comment: the error returned (a bit different) : http://pastebin.com/kqTE6RjW

Comment: did you resolved it?

Comment: @goto no sorry, I never succeed to make this bundle work as I expected, and I kept using html2pdf. Are you facing the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
$snappy->setOption('footer-html', 'http://www.google.com');
```

The second argument in the setOption() method is looking for a html file on the local filesystem.  As it is written currently it would try to include the Google homepage as a footer on every page of your pdf.   Try something like this instead:

```
$snappy->setOption('footer-html', 'path/to/footer.html');
$snappy->getOutput('https://google.com');
```

Be aware that the `.html` is important, non-standard extension names like `.phtml` will cause errors.